# kafka controllers + root cause of re-elect in worse case scenario

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

We have the Kafka controller logs from a 3-node Kafka cluster version 0.10 , which got into a bad state after ZK expired:

```
[2024-01-09 18:33:42,897] INFO [SessionExpirationListener on 2], ZK expired; 
shut down all controller components and try to re-elect 
(kafka.controller.KafkaController$SessionExpirationListener)
[2024-01-17 05:06:13,469] INFO [SessionExpirationListener on 2], ZK expired; 
shut down all controller components and try to re-elect 
(kafka.controller.KafkaController$SessionExpirationListener)
[2024-01-17 16:33:43,349] INFO [SessionExpirationListener on 2], ZK expired; 
shut down all controller components and try to re-elect 
(kafka.controller.KafkaController$SessionExpirationListener)
[2024-01-17 16:33:44,059] INFO [Controller 2]: Broker 2 starting become 
controller state transition (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
{noformat}
```

Not clear what can be the reasons about shut down all controller components and try to re-elect
But seems its more related to Kafka issue and not zookeeper issue

In any case the code is as the following ( Register zk's `SessionExpiration` event notification: `registerSessionExpirationListener` When the session expires and a new session is established, the controller is re-elected; )

```
/**

     * Called after the zookeeper session has expired and a new session has been created. You would have to re-create

     * any ephemeral nodes here.

     *

     * @throwsException _

     *On any error.

     */

    @ throws (classOf[Exception])

    def handleNewSession() {

      info( "ZK expired; shut down all controller components and try to re-elect" )

      inLock(controllerContext.controllerLock) {

        onControllerResignation()

        controllerElector.elect

      }

    }

  }
```

The results of the described exception could be session from broker to zk expires and the broker will not actively initiate a reconnection operation

But the question is what can be the reasons when we get this exception from controller logs - `shut down all controller components and try to re-elect`